# escapeinside doesn't work with tcolorbox in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tcolorbox, minted

I am trying to make a `beamer` presentation with the following `tcblisting` declaration in the preamble.

```
\newtcblisting{ListingBoxWithEscape}[2][]{
minted language=#2,
minted style=friendly,
minted options={breaklines,autogobble,fontsize=\footnotesize,tabsize=2,escapeinside=!!},
title=#1
}
```

In my document I have:

```
\begin{ListingBoxWithEscape}{html}
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Grid Cols and a Row</h1>!
        \tikz \node[coordinate] (a) {};
        !<p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect</p>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Web Design</h3>
          <p>This is Web design. This is web design. This is web design..</p>
          <p>We are trying to learn Responsive web design using Bootstrap......</p>
        </div>
\end{ListingBoxWithEscape}
```

To which I get the following errors:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...                                              

l.6 \PYG{esc}{    \tikz \node[coordinate] (a) {};}
```

I am unable to figure out what the problem may be. Anybody have any ideas?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{xparse,minted}

\newtcblisting{ListingBoxWithEscape}[2][]{
    minted language=#2,
    minted style=friendly,
    minted options={breaklines,autogobble,fontsize=\footnotesize,tabsize=2,escapeinside=!!},
    title=#1
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c,fragile]
    \frametitle{Test}
    \begin{ListingBoxWithEscape}{html}
        <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Grid Cols and a Row</h1>!
            \tikz \node[coordinate] (a) {};
            !<p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect</p>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Web Design</h3>
              <p>This is Web design. This is web design. This is web design..</p>
              <p>We are trying to learn Responsive web design using Bootstrap......</p>
            </div>
    \end{ListingBoxWithEscape}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that if I hide the `tikzpicture` in a command, say `\newcommand\tst{\tikz[remember picture]{\coordinate (a);}}`, and then use this command, the error message is gone. The following has many inputs from @egreg, whom I thank for the comments below. As @egreg points out, the issue are the `{` and `}`, I was only guessing that something in (I thought there is something fundamentally wrong, but as @egreg pointed out you may want to add `listing only`.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{xparse,minted}

\newtcblisting{ListingBoxWithEscape}[2][]{listing only,
    minted language=#2,
    minted style=friendly,
    minted options={breaklines,autogobble,fontsize=\footnotesize,tabsize=2,
    escapeinside=!!},
    title=#1
}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts,shapes.arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c,fragile]
\newcommand\tst{\tikz[remember picture]{\coordinate (a);}}
    \frametitle{Test}
    \begin{ListingBoxWithEscape}{html}
        <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Grid Cols and a Row</h1>!\tst!
            <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect</p>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <h3>Web Design</h3>
              <p>This is Web design. This is web design. This is web design..</p>
              <p>We are trying to learn Responsive web design using Bootstrap......</p>
            </div>
    \end{ListingBoxWithEscape}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red,latex-] (a) to[out=0,in=-90] ++ (1,1) node[above] {test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it's a problem of category codes; for some reason `{}` doesn't get recognized for the node label. Hiding the picture in a macro solves the issue because the replacement text is tokenized in advance.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Yes, that makes sense. I am however concerned about the lower half of the tcolorbox, this seems to be rubbish, regardless of the escape stuff.

Comment: I guess the OP forgot to add `listing only`

Comment: @egreg Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: The temporary definition can better be done inside the frame, prior to the `ListingBoxWithEscape` environment.

Comment: @egreg Thanks again. You could then write an answer using `\tikz\coordinate(a);`, which is equivalent to the OP's command but does not require braces. I checked, it runs through, as you predict.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a strange problem to have and one I think should be documented in the package documentation. @egreg is correct I indeed had a `tcbset` with the `listing only` option that I forgot to copy into my MWE.